# JavaScript: Create function that returns an object whose keys match the elements in the array of values using callbacks

Tags: javascript, function, loops, callback, arguments

My objective is as follows:

Construct a function multiMap that will accept two arrays - an array of values and an array of callbacks. multiMap will return an object whose keys match the elements in the array of values. The corresponding values that are assigned to the keys will be arrays consisting of outputs from the array of callbacks, where the input to each callback is the key.

I tried the code below:

```
const multiMap = (arrOne, arrTwo) => {

  let newObj = {}; 

  for (let i=0; i<arrOne.length; i++){
    let element = arrOne[i]; 

    console.log(i)

    newObj[element] = arrTwo[i](element); 
  }
  return newObj; 
}



// Uncomment these to check your work!
function uppercaser(str) { return str.toUpperCase(); }
function capitalize(str) { return str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).toLowerCase(); }
function repeater(str) { return str + str; }

// arrOne
const items = ['catfood', 'glue', 'beer'];
// arrTwo
const functions = [uppercaser, capitalize, repeater];


console.log(multiMap(items, functions));
```

My code returns: `{ catfood: 'CATFOOD', glue: 'Glue', beer: 'beerbeer' }`

I want it to return: `{ catfood: ['CATFOOD', 'Catfood', 'catfoodcatfood'], glue: ['GLUE', 'Glue', 'glueglue'], beer: ['BEER', 'Beer', 'beerbeer'] }, 'Beer', 'beerbeer'] }`

What am I doing wrong?

Note: I know I can use modifying functions (i.e. reduce) to do this but I want to figure it out first using for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are looping only over the first array. You have to go through all the functions for each value in the array one.

```js
const multiMap = (arrOne, arrTwo) => {

  let newObj = {}; 

  for (let i=0; i<arrOne.length; i++){
    let element = arrOne[i];
    newObj[element] = [];
    for(let j=0;j < arrTwo.length; j++) {
     
    newObj[element].push(arrTwo[j](element)); 
    }
  }
  return newObj; 
}



// Uncomment these to check your work!
function uppercaser(str) { return str.toUpperCase(); }
function capitalize(str) { return str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).toLowerCase(); }
function repeater(str) { return str + str; }

// arrOne
const items = ['catfood', 'glue', 'beer'];
// arrTwo
const functions = [uppercaser, capitalize, repeater];


console.log(multiMap(items, functions));
```

Answer (score 1):

A more functional solution would be,

```js
const multiMap = (arrVals, arrCallbacks) => arrVals.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr] = arrCallbacks.map(cb => cb(curr));
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(multiMap(['catfood', 'glue', 'beer'], [(str) => str.toUpperCase(), (str) => str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).toLowerCase(), (str) => str + str]));
// should log: { catfood: ['CATFOOD', 'Catfood', 'catfoodcatfood'], glue: ['GLUE', 'Glue', 'glueglue'], beer: ['BEER', 'Beer', 'beerbeer'] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over the function array in order to create an the associated array of results.

```js
const multiMap = (arrOne, arrTwo) => {

  let newObj = {}; 

  for (let i=0; i<arrOne.length; i++){
    let element = arrOne[i]; 

    console.log(i)

    var arr = [];
    for (let f=0;f<functions.length;f++) {
      arr.push(functions[f](element));
    }

    newObj[element] = arr; 
  }
  return newObj; 
}



// Uncomment these to check your work!
function uppercaser(str) { return str.toUpperCase(); }
function capitalize(str) { return str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).toLowerCase(); }
function repeater(str) { return str + str; }

// arrOne
const items = ['catfood', 'glue', 'beer'];
// arrTwo
const functions = [uppercaser, capitalize, repeater];


console.log(multiMap(items, functions));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two additional (more basic) ways to solve this to help with the learning process:

```js
function multiMap(vals, CB) {
/* 
// OPTION 1: ----------------------------------------------------------------

  let fOut = {};
  
  for (let i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
    let e = vals[i];
    
    fOut[e] = [];   // set key = empty arr
    
    for (let j = 0; j < CB.length; j++) {   // nested for loop to populate value arr
      fOut[e].push(CB[j](e));
    }
    
  }
  return fOut;
 */

  
// OPTION 2: ----------------------------------------------------------------
  let fOut = {};    // initalize empty object for results
  
    vals.forEach( (e) => {    // for each element in the vals arr:
        fOut[e] = CB.map( (funct) => {    // map each function of the CB arr
            return funct(e);
        });
    });
  
    return fOut;
}
```